# mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

When I use this method first time it works fine, but when I called it second time I get the error "mutating method sent to immutable object". The problem is at line with "addObject" command.

```
-(IBAction) save: (id) sender{

NSMutableArray *placesT= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"placesT"];

if (!placesT) {
    placesT=[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
}

[placesT addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tagF.text] ];

NSUserDefaults *tUD=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[tUD setObject:placesT forKey:@"placesT"];
[tUD synchronize];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

}

Comment: Well the problem is with the  placesT initialization. My bet is  the NSUserDefault standard is empty the first time and goes to the second init. You also have a memory leak ther.

Comment: Note that you can probably replace `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tagF.text]` with `tagF.text` only. There’s no need to send `+stringWithFormat:` if `text` is already an `NSString`.

Answer (score 24):

As the documentation for NSUserDefaults says: "Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value." Whenever you want to change a collection you get from NSUserDefaults you have to get the immutable version, make a `mutableCopy`, modify that, and set it back again.

Comment: to add to this that would be for example:  someMutableArray = [yourArrayFromDictionary mutableCopy];   hope that helped :)

Answer (score 10):

That is because the object stored in the NSUserDefaults is not the mutableArray but a normal array.

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

   NSMutableArray *placesT = nil;
   NSArray *tempArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"placesT"];

   if (tempArray) {
      placesT = [tempArray mutableCopy];
   } else {
      placesT = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   }

   [placesT addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tagF.text]];

   NSUserDefaults *tUD = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [tUD setObject:placesT forKey:@"placesT"];
   [tUD synchronize];

   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   [placesT release];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

placesT is a non mutable array, either always set `placesT` a mutable object always or use following code.

```
NSMutableArray *placesT= [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"placesT"] mutableCopy];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

> -(IBAction) save: (id) sender {
>
> ```
> NSMutableArray *placesT= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
> ```
>
> objectForKey:@"placesT"]];
>
> ```
> if (!placesT) {
>     placesT=[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
> }
>
> [placesT addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tagF.text] ];
>
> NSUserDefaults *tUD=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
> [tUD setObject:placesT forKey:@"placesT"];
> [tUD synchronize];
>
> [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; }
> ```