# Cannot update NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: swift, nsmutabledictionary

I do not understand why I'm getting an error on this method:

```
let loginCountKey = "loginCount"
let appReviewParamsKey = "appReviewParams"

func resetLoginCount() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let reviewParameters = defaults.valueForKey(appReviewParamsKey) as? NSMutableDictionary {
        reviewParameters[loginCountKey] = 1

        defaults.setObject(reviewParameters, forKey: appReviewParamsKey)
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

the setObject line give me an error: `caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", ... mutating method sent to immutable object"`

When debugging, reviewParameters shows as an NSMutableDictionary. I also tried an if var instead of an if let (tho it should be unnecessary) and got the same error.

I also tried setting the value to NSNumber(int: 1) instead of just 1.

Why would this cause the given error?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790715/mutating-method-sent-to-immutable-object

Comment: No worries. This came as a surprise to me too.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

- `NSUserDefaults` returns immutable objects when casted to Foundation types
- Even if the returned value was mutable you assigned it to a constant (let) which makes the object immutable in Swift.

In Swift the recommended way is to use native Swift types and variables (var) for example

```
func resetLoginCount() {
  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

  if var reviewParameters = defaults.objectForKey(appReviewParamsKey) as? [String:AnyObject] {
    reviewParameters[loginCountKey] = 1

    defaults.setObject(reviewParameters, forKey: appReviewParamsKey)
    defaults.synchronize()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults.objectForKey` (which the general KVC method `valueForKey` has to call through to) returns an immutable `NSDictionary` when it finds dictionary-format data for that defaults key.

Using `as?` is a *cast*, not a *conversion*. That is, you're telling Swift to interpret the dictionary you have *as if it were* an `NSMutableDictionary` (even though it's not, which is why this fails). If you want to *convert* an `NSDictionary` into an `NSMutableDictionary`, you'll need to create an instance of the latter from the former (with `mutableCopy` or `initWithDictionary:`).

But you don't even need to work with Foundation dictionaries here — an `NSDictionary` is automatically bridged to a Swift dictionary, and you can cast to interpret it `as` the right key/value types. And you can bind an optional as a mutable value by using `if var` instead of `if let`:

```
if var reviewParameters = defaults.objectForKey(appReviewParamsKey) as? [String: Int] {
    reviewParameters[loginCountKey] = 1

    defaults.setObject(reviewParameters, forKey: appReviewParamsKey)
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```